# How to sort a Json array c#

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, sorting, arraylist, c#-3.0

I've got a time problem.
And although I have a project on autonomous because one of our developers has failed. The Project was implemented in C # Asp.Net MVC. And I have actually not as much to do with it since I'm actually rather responsible for Mobiele applications.
And then I have found the solution always on the look but I'm just simply not on.

And it is so we call on to get data from the database and pass it to a jqgrid. I know this because there are probably problems with the General Order. But I am now only at times between a solution. I want to sort the arry issue and indeed descending.

ah yes sorry for the bad english.

find attached the code from the controller:

```
enter code here  public class KalkulationController : BaseController
{
    private IOrderedEnumerable<KalkulationMasterModel> array;

    #region JSON

    public virtual ActionResult List( string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, decimal? anr)
    {

        if (!anr.HasValue)
            return null;

        var service = new KalkulationMasterService();

        var listOfKalkulation = service.GetListOfKalkulation(anr, Nutzer);
      //  array = listOfKalkulation.OrderByDescending(c => c);
        var jsonData = new 
                           {
                               total = 0,
                               page = page,
                               records = 10,
                               rows = (
                                          listOfKalkulation.Select(k => new 
                                                                            {
                                                                                i = k.AuftragId,
                                                                              //  k.OrderBy(k => k.Id);
                                                                                cell = new string[]
                                                                                           {
                                                                                               k.Id.ToString(),
                                                                                               k.AuftragId.HasValue?k.AuftragId.Value.ToString():null,
                                                                                               k.Bestellnummer.HasValue?k.Bestellnummer.Value.ToString():null,
                                                                                               k.NumberOfArt.HasValue?k.NumberOfArt.Value.ToString():null,
                                                                                               k.LT.HasValue ? k.LT.Value.ToString() : null,
                                                                                               k.AAStatus??string.Empty,
                                                                                               k.Los.ToString(),
                                                                                               //k.Einheit,          
                                                                                               //String.Format("{0:0.00}",k.Gesamtgewicht),                                                                                                   
                                                                                               //String.Format("{0:0.00}",k.Preis),
                                                                                               String.Format("{0:0.00}",k.KundenPreis),
                                                                                               String.Format("{0:0.00}",k.KorekturPreis),                                                                                                   
                                                                                               k.ArtikelNr.ToString()
                                                                                           }

                                                                            })).ToArray()

                           };

        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you want to sort by, but below is an example to order by ID (Ascending).  You need to chain the .OrderBy() either before or after your select (in the examples below, I order before doing the select as noted by the **OrderBy** in the code snippets below.

```
var jsonData = new{
                   total = 0,
                   page = page,
                   records = 10,
                   rows = (
                           listOfKalkulation.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).Select(k => new...
```

Sort by ID (Descending)

```
var jsonData = new{
                       total = 0,
                       page = page,
                       records = 10,
                       rows = (
                               listOfKalkulation.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id).Select(k => new...
```

And...ordering by the Los property (random selection from your cells)

```
var jsonData = new{
                   total = 0,
                   page = page,
                   records = 10,
                   rows = (
                           listOfKalkulation.OrderBy(x=>x.Los).Select(k => new...
```